# jsf multiple forms in single page. 1st form submit trigger. 2nd form submit just refreshing page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a two forms in single jsf page.

The 1st form submit getting triggered. trigger. But the 2nd form submit not working. It just refreshing the page. What could be the issue?

Create Form:

```
<h:form id="createUnitForm">
<f:event listener="#{bean.validateCreate}" type="postValidate" />
<a4j:outputPanel id="createPanel">
<rich:panel rendered="#{bean.isCreate()}">
<h:inputText id="defaultInt" value="#{bean.value}"></h:inputText>
<rich:message for="defaultInt" />
</rich:panel>
</a4j:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

Update Form:

```
<h:form id="updateUnitForm">
<f:event listener="#{bean.validateUpdate}" type="postValidate" />
<a4j:outputPanel id="updatePanel">
<rich:panel rendered="#{bean.isUpdate()}">
<h:inputText id="defaultIntU" value="#{bean.value}"></h:inputText>
<rich:message for="defaultIntU" />
</rich:panel>
</a4j:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

Note: If I have only 2nd form, then it is working.

Comment: I also have the same problem. I would like to see how this can be solved.

Comment: @PeterPenzov May be you have nested form